# How can I duplicate rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, which shows information regarding trades. `d_diff` column shows the difference between `endtime` and `begtime`, measured in a number of days.

I want those rows, where `d_diff > 1`, to make duplicated (`d_diff` shows the number of duplicated rows.

[image]

The final dataset should look like in a table below. As you can see, in this table the difference between `endtime` and `begtime` is 1 (the table is more granular).

[image]

How can it be done?
I tried to do kind of this

```
select * from main a
full outer join 
main b
on a.begtime <= b.endtime
```

Answer (score 1):

You can *inner join* with a tally table / numbers list.

Example:

```
with tally as (
  select v from (values(1),(2),(3))v(v)
)
select m.* 
from main m
join tally t on t.v <= m.d_diff;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE to generate series of repeatable rows like this

```
WITH cte(begtime, endtime, d_diff, trade, tradedate, price, region, d_diff_decr) AS (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        d_diff AS d_diff_decr 
    FROM t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        begtime, 
        endtime, 
        d_diff, 
        trade, 
        tradedate, 
        price, 
        region, 
        d_diff_decr - 1 AS d_diff_decr 
    FROM cte 
    WHERE d_diff_decr > 1
)
SELECT 
    begtime, 
    endtime, 
    d_diff, 
    trade, 
    tradedate, 
    price, 
    region 
FROM cte
ORDER BY trade
```